# Typo in the example "custom layer in Tensorflow using Keras"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I think there is a typo in the Tensorflow [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#build_a_model%20Custom%20layer%20using%20Keras) for building a custom layer using Keras. The tutorial is on using Eager mode.  The only missing part is

```
super(MySimpleLayer, self).__init__()
```

in the **init** method:

```
class MySimpleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, output_units):
    **super(MySimpleLayer, self).__init__()**
    self.output_units = output_units

  def build(self, input):
    # The build method gets called the first time your layer is used.
    # Creating variables on build() allows you to make their shape depend
    # on the input shape and hence remove the need for the user to specify
    # full shapes. It is possible to create variables during __init__() if
    # you already know their full shapes.
    self.kernel = self.add_variable(
      "kernel", [input.shape[-1], self.output_units])

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **init** method just needs:

```
super(MySimpleLayer, self).__init__()
```

Without this line, errors of missing attributes will be shown, such as:

```
AttributeError: 'MySimpleLayer' object has no attribute '_scope'
```

, that are parts of the parent class.